# How do I create database driven route aliases in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I'm developing a content management system with a database driven menu system which will allow users to generate SEO friendly URLs to the application routes defined in `routes.php`.

For example, the user creates a menu item to a Page with the desired path `/about-us`. When a request is made, the application checks for the existence of an alias for the current path in the database and then routes the request according to it's alias.

The desired result is when you request `/about-us` the application actually treats it as `/pages/1`, but the user sees `/about-us` in the address bar.

The user needs to be able link to any resource, not just pages - so categories, posts, etc.

Example menu item model:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "About us page",
    "path": "/about-us",
    "alias": "/pages/1"
}
```

Example target routes:

```
Route::get('pages/{id}', 'PageController@show');
Route::get('categories/{id}', 'CategoryController@show');
```

I thought perhaps I could simply override the `REQUEST_URI` variable using a before filter registered in `start/global.php` but this had no effect.

```
App::before(function(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    $request_uri = $request->server->get('REQUEST_URI');
    $request_uri_string = urldecode(substr($request_uri, 1));

    if (strlen($request_uri_string)>1) 
    {
        if ($menuItem = MenuItem::where('path', '=', $request_uri_string)->first())
        {
            $request->server->set('REQUEST_URI', $menuItem->alias);
        }
    }
});
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I've found the solution to this by extending `\Illuminate\Http\Request` and injecting this custom request class into the application in `bootstrap/start.php`.

Custom Request class:

```
namespace Vendor\Package;

class Request extends \Illuminate\Http\Request {

    /**
     * Override the request uri so we can create menu aliases
     *
     * @param $value
     */
    public function setRequestUri($value)
    {
        $this->requestUri = $value;
        $this->pathInfo = $value;
        $this->server->set('REQUEST_URI', $value);
    }

}
```

Inject custom Request class into the application at the top of `bootstrap/start.php`

```
$request = \Vendor\Package\Request::createFromGlobals();
$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application($request);
```

Check for the existence of a menu item with the requested path and set the request uri as its alias (`app/start/global.php`).

```
App::before(function(Vendor\Package\Request $request)
{
    $request_uri = $request->server->get('REQUEST_URI');
    $request_uri_string = urldecode(substr($request_uri, 1));

    if (strlen($request_uri_string)>1)
    {
        if ($menuItem = MenuItem::where('path', '=', $request_uri_string)->first())
        {
            $request->setRequestUri($menuItem->alias);
        }
    }
});
```